# JSF 2/PrimeFaces 4.0: Can a link in a row expand the row?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, rowexpansion

Given the code below (taken from the [PrimeFaces ShowCase)](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/expansion.xhtml), what is the best way to change the functionality so that the text in the second column - `<h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />` - acts as a link to expand/contract the row (rather than the `<p:rowToggler>` image)?

Not sure how easy this is/should be, but I'm pretty new to PrimeFaces and unsure of how this could be done. I've looked through the documentation and the [PrimeFaces ShowCase)](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/expansion.xhtml), (and played with similar code for a few hours), but I've been unable to get it done.

***ShowCase code:***

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Expand rows to see detailed information
        </f:facet>
        <p:column style="width:16px">
            <p:rowToggler />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />  <!-- This text needs to be a link that expands the row -->
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Year">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:rowExpansion>
            <p:panelGrid  columns="2" columnClasses="label,value" style="width:300px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/car/#{car.brand}-big.gif"/> 
                </f:facet>

                <h:outputText value="Id:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />

                <h:outputText value="Year" />
                <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />

                <h:outputText value="Color:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" style="color:#{car.color}"/>

                <h:outputText value="Price" />
                <h:outputText value="$#{car.price}" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:rowExpansion>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

---

***Edit*** - Found a simple solution, but not sure it's the most elegant. Any reason not to use this?

```
<p:column style="display:none !important">
    <p:rowToggler />
</p:column>
<p:column>
    <h:outputLink value="#">#{car.id}</h:outputLink>
</p:column>`
```

Answer (score 1):

The default PrimeFaces configuration doesn't allow for anything else than a `<p:rowToggler />` to toggle a `<p:rowExpansion>`.

One solution could be using some custom JS functions to add/remove CSS classes on generated HTML elements.

The other solution can be found here : http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11308&p=55114#p55114. It's about modifying PrimeFaces sources to match your needs.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I found another way to get it done, but curious if there is an advantage to some JS over it: 
I placed the `<p:rowToggler>` in a `<p:column>` with `display:none`:

`<p:column style="display:none !important"><p:rowToggler /></p:column>` 
Thoughts?

Comment: Well i don't see how your solution allows the user to expand the `<p:rowExpansion>` after clicking on the id column.

Comment: The `<p:rowToggler>` isn't displayed, but is still expanding the `<p:rowExpansion>`, although it appears that the `<h:outputLink>` being clicked is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

There is a easy way to do that. Create a link in a div and modify the class of the div with "ui-row-toggler" which you can get from rowToggler html source. e.g.

```
<div class="ui-row-toggler"><a href="##" class="ui-row-toggler">Test</a></div>
```

The reason you can do that is because if you check the html source for primefaces row toggler, you can find it is

```
<div class="ui-row-toggler ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e"></div>
```

So the only thing you need to do is putting the same class to your customized div which has a link inside.